# Selection sort Pointer issue

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm having trouble with my selection sort. It's not sorting the list in ascending order, in fact it's not doing anything according to my debugger. I noticed when I debugged it on line 42 it skips the conditional statement and I am not understanding why it is doing that. I think the problem is in the 2nd for loop in the if statement. The conditional statement is false, when it should be true.  If you could guide me to the right direction I would gladly appreciate. I'm here to learn.

```
#include <iostream>
void sortAscendingOrder(int*, int );
int main()
{
    int* array = nullptr;
    int input;

    std::cout << "Enter the number of testscores you want to enter." <<std::endl;
    std::cin >> input;

    array = new int[input];

    for(int count =0; count < input; count++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the test score" << (count +1) <<":" <<std::endl;
        std::cin >> *(array+count);
    }

    sortAscendingOrder(array,input);

    for(int count =0; count < input;count++)
    {
        std::cout << "\n" << *(array+count);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }




    return 0;
}
void sortAscendingOrder(int* input,int size)
{
    int startScan,minIndex,minValue;

    for(startScan =0; startScan < (size-1);startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = *(input+startScan);
        for(int index = startScan+1;index<size;index++)
        {
            if(*(input+startScan) < minValue) // Here this condition is false. 
            {
                minValue = *(input+index);
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        *(input+minIndex)=*(input+startScan);
        *(input+startScan)=minValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is line 42?

Comment: `if(*(input+startScan) < minValue)`, I'm not sure why this statement is false when it should be true.

Comment: what value you are getting in input??

Comment: So, I enter 3 as my number of testscores I want. The values I enter are 45,100,40. According to my debugger input is holding a value of 45 always

Comment: Congratulations on a pretty good question.  *Next* time remember that we don't need to see your whole program - just the bit you are having trouble with.  Rather than reading your values from `cin`, it would have been better to write:  `int array[] = { 45, 100, 40 }; int input = 3;` - that's less code for us to read, and rishit_s wouldn't have had to ask what the values are.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

startScan is the starting position for finding the minimum value.

```
if(*(input+startScan) < minValue)
```

is never never true, the left hand side and right hand side are always equal.

It looks like you want to say

```
if(*(input + index) < minValue)
```

Your debugger should be able to produce the value of `*(input + startScan)` as a watch or as an expression for your future debugging sessions.

Comment: Thank you, that makes more sense I can see now why it the conditional statement was always false. Stupid mistake on my part, didn't see it.

Comment: I'm quite new to debugging so, I will keep that in mind. Thanks again.